# missing "channel" within ExpressionEngine control panel

Tags: expressionengine

i am fairly new to expression engine, i have noticed my admin page is missing "Channel" "template" and "template group" as seen on this page

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/how_to/building_a_simple_news_site.html#before-you-begin

Can someone please advise?

many thanks

Comment: You should post this to the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks i will post the question on the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you create a channel, a template group or a template, all three will not have any content in the control panel - expressionengine, by default, installs as a blank slate.  Have you created any of the three?

Comment: i have a website up and running (using channels / templates) however within the admin control panel i do not see any option to create new channels

Comment: Are you logged in as a super admin? Super Admins would see everything, regardless of permissions that can be assigned to non-super admin groups.  Adding a channel would be under admin > channel administration > channels

Comment: i am logged in as admin, i do not see channel under admin

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in as a super admin? The group ID would be "1". Any other group, and you could be subject to permission limitations. Is this another developer someone else set up? You mention you have a full site but that you're new to expressionengine, which is why I ask.